# How do you build an NSURL for an image in Image.xcassets?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

The easiest way to load a local `UIImage` asset is of course to use `+[UIImage imageNamed]` but for my case, I want to supply a `NSURL *`. How do I get a `NSURL *` for local file?

Comment: If it is in your image assets, you should not need to use an NSURL...

Comment: Simply speaking there is no way as such.

Comment: "I need to supply a NSURL *" No you don't.

Comment: -_- had this been a question about any other local file it'd be a valid question and not been downvoted. I'm trying to build an abstraction for which the image is not necessarily available to be passed around until it's been fetched from the server. It's perfectly reasonable to want to standardize the interface to use NSURL's instead of UIImage.

Comment: @matt fine — 'want' then, not need.

Comment: Actually, there are situations when you must have an NSURL for images in an asset catalog or sticker pack.  You can't create an MSSticker with only UIImage.  The API allows only file URLs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msstickerview?language=objc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While using xcasset, Xcode put all your files in a new one. 1 file to manage them all. So, you can't access to an image store inside an xcasset directly. From apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html):

> For projects with a deployment target of at least iOS 7 or OS X 10.9,
>   Xcode compiles your asset catalogs into a runtime binary file format
>   that reduces the download time for your app.

If you have to access to the file, you have two choice:

- Don't use the xcasset for this image, but put your image as an normal image in your project and use the `NSBundle` to get it
- Use `UIImage imageNamed`, and save it in the directory of your choice

But whatever your need, you should think another way to manage it. The above solutions will work, but I'm sure you can have a nicer solution.